# Is SQL DEFINER MODE disabled in CREATE VIEW syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> CREATE OR REPLACE SQL SECURITY  DEFINER view cat as SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cats;


mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.6.24    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This view is enabled for all users . 
Is `SQL DEFINER MODE` disabled in `CREATE VIEW` syntax?